# Performance tuning MongoDB query/update?

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have a MongoDB instance where I am trying to update data in one collection with data from another collection.  The two collections are `participants` with about 180k documents and  `questions` with about 95k documents.

Documents in `participants` typically look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52f90b8bbab16dd8594b82b4"),
    "answers" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52f90b8bbab16dd8594b82b9"),
            "question_id" : 2081,
            "sub_id" : null,
            "values" : [
                "Yes"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52f90b8bbab16dd8594b82b8"),
            "question_id" : 2082,
            "sub_id" : 123,
            "values" : [
                "Would prefer to go alone"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52f90b8bbab16dd8594b82b7"),
            "question_id" : 2082,
            "sub_id" : 456,
            "values" : [
                "Yes"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "created" : ISODate("2012-03-01T17:40:21Z"),
    "email" : "anonymous",
    "id" : 65,
    "survey" : ObjectId("52f41d579af1ff4221399a7b"),
    "survey_id" : 374
}
```

I am using the query below to perform the update:

```
db.participants.ensureIndex({"answers.question_id": 1, "answers.sub_id": 1});
print("created index for answer arrays!")
db.questions.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.participants.update(
        {
            "answers.question_id": doc.id,
            "answers.sub_id": doc.sub_id
        },
        {
            $set:
            {
                "answers.$.question": doc._id
            }

        },
        false,
        true
    );
});
db.participants.dropIndex({"answers.question_id": 1, "answers.sub_id": 1});
```

But this takes about 20 minutes to run.  I was hoping that adding the index would help with the performance, but it is still pretty slow.  Is this index setup correctly considering that I am indexing fields in an array of objects?  Can anyone see anything that I am doing that would cause the slowness?  Suggestions on where to start looking to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: What's the point of invoking dropIndex after the query?

How about the result of "explain()" of your query?

    db.participants.find({
            "answers.question_id": doc.id,
            "answers.sub_id": doc.sub_id
    }).explain()

Comment: I think this would be a lot faster if you could express it as a mapreduce job, that way it would all execute in the database server without involving the network.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is not a separate application that is executing this script.  This is a pure MongoDB script that I am executing from the shell.  With that said, do you still think the network is involved?

Comment: @AbeMiessler The comments are on the answer. This script is not running on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested I was able to take the run time of this update query from 20 minutes down to about a minute and a half by using projection when selecting the `questions` documents.  Since I am only using the `_id`, `id` and `sub_id` fields I was able to do the following:

```
db.questions.find({},{_id: 1, id: 1, sub_id: 1}).forEach(function(doc){
    ....
```

Which drastically improved performance.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to consider what you are *actually* doing here in order to understand why the index is not helping and indeed why this operation takes so long.

The first part of the answer is explained by what you are doing here:

```
db.questions.find()
```

Now that part alone basically says that you are asking to retrieve every document in your `questions` collection. So we can see what you are trying to do is exactly that, as you want to update that content into your `participants` collection, particularly the document _id for the "question". But here, by definition of getting all documents, no index will be used.

So what you are doing is looping every document in the `questions`, then asking with your **update** operation to *match* the `participants` record with data from the "question". And what that means is you are pulling "over the wire" all of your 95K documents and sending back "over the wire" your update operation, 95K times. This is not happening on the server and there is network traffic between your application and your MongoDB.

The index itself is not going to do much other than improve the search of each `participants` record, which is better than scanning and you should be getting the match. But that's not the part that taking the time, its the fetching of the `questions` that will be the largest issue. Also note that if you were updating

So if it's possible to run your update process on a machine that is as close as possible in networking terms to the MongoDB server then that is going to be your best performance improvement. You could also wind back your [**Write Concern**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/) if you want to be a little daring and/or can live with checking the integrity in another opertation, and that will reduce your network traffic and waiting for a response to the update (which is actually happening) if you put it in "**fire and forget**" mode.

Also see the guide if you are not sure of the concepts:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/

Comment: Just to clarify, there is not a separate application that is executing this script.  This is a pure MongoDB script that I am executing from the shell.  With that said, do your "over the wire" concerns still apply?

Comment: Yes. The shell is just another client. You are not executing on the server, which is what I thought you assumed you were doing.

Comment: Oh interesting, so is it ever possible to execute on the server?  My client and server are running on the same machine...

Comment: Also it seems like a piece of your answer may have been cut off here: `Also note that if you were updating`.  Was there something that was supposed to go after that?